# Does Allah have emotions?

Tags: quran, allah

Somewhere I've heard, that emotions are transient things, but Allah is ethernal. And thus, Allah can't have emotions. It deeply surprised me, because I think, the only reason for the supreme being to create the world is the love. He doesn't need us, we can't give Him anything which he would need.

Thus, the only reason for Him to create us, is that He loves us. If you have a million of dollars, there is no problem for you to give a cent (or even much more) to a poor man.

But these are only my speculations.

Do the Quran mentions anything about Allah's emotions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call the possessing of the following qualities - [Mercy](http://quran.com/search?q=merciful), [Love](http://quran.com/85/14), [Anger](http://quran.com/1/7) as emotions, then YES, Allah has emotions. As they're described in Qur'an in many places.

If you ask Does Allah has emotions like us,

then I would say NO, because comparing ourselves with Allah is highly not advisable, but still to answer, we might call ourselves possessing these qualities too i.e. Mercy, Love, Anger, but we won't be expressing them perfectly or always whenever necessary. But Allah's way of expressing emotions remains constant towards a person or creation of his if that person/creation meets the necessary conditions.

May the creator guide us all.